# this.router.back() With parameter in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Using Nativescript 5.0 + Angular

Unable to figure out how can I accomplish it?

1. From first view (referred in this post as original view), user taps a button
2. this.router.navigate(["secure/booking/city"]) displays new view having  listview
3. User taps the city item he want to select from the view
4. this.router.back() is called onItemTap
5. User can see the original screen

I want city item details (name & ID) back to the original view.

I have tried using ApplicationSettings from second view and read back in original view, but not happening.

Below is the code snip

```
 this.router.navigate(["secure/booking/city"]).then((response) => {
                console.log("ret data name : " + ApplicationSettings.getString("cityname"));    
                ApplicationSettings.setString("cityname","");
            }, (e) => {
                console.log("error -ret data name : " + ApplicationSettings.getString("cityname"));   
            });
```

Comment: You could simply use a Service with BehaviorSubject, subscribe to it in the original view and update the BehaviorSubject as needed.

Comment: It worked. Thanks Manoj.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, added same as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a Service with BehaviorSubject, subscribe to it in the original view and update the BehaviorSubject as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the reply by Manoj, here is the detailed solution.

declare variable in DataService ts file

public retParam = new BehaviorSubject('');

In first view's html:

```
<Label [text]="this._Service.retParam.getValue()" verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
```

In first view's ts file
public constructor(private _Service: DataService)

In second view's ts file
inside onItemTap event handler

this._Service.retParam.next("Pratik");

This way, when app starts, label from first view shows empty string
There is a button in first view.

By tapping this button, second view is loaded with a list view
onItemTap  of listview, value of retParam is set and 
this.router.back(); is called

This brings the control back to first view and the Label now shows my name instead of blank string.

Hope this explanation is useful for beginners like me.